# akka-quartz-scheduler - "No matching quartz configuration found for schedule" - QuartzSchedulerExtension shared between two actors

Tags: scala, akka

I'm sharing QuartzSchedulerExtension instance (akka-quartz-scheduler version 1.8.1) between two actors.

In some situations seems that "No matching quartz configuration found for schedule" is thrown when both actors are working on scheduler in the same time.
Looks like QuartzSchedulerExtension is not thread safe.

**Is it possible to share QuartzSchedulerExtension safely or only way is to wrap it up in single actor and expose its api as messages on this actor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this issue on GitHub its not safe to use Scheduler in more than one actor:
https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler/issues/33